# Got stucked with a small JS code

Tags: javascript, html

I got stucked with some part of my "web app"... All I need is to view the value of the function "calculate" by clicking the button "calculate". Function value should appear in the element with the class "rez". Here is my code:

**JS**

```
function calculate() {

    var bmi = teza / (visina*visina);

    document.getElementsByClassName("rez").value = bmi;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <p><b>BMI za izbrano osebo:</b></p>
    <div class="res"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `teza` , `visina` and `visina`  these are undefined variable .show your complete code and show your  `console.log` error (`f12` mode)

Comment: they are defined before.

Comment: show your complete code

Comment: Please share your code. Don't you see any errors in the developer console?

Comment: i just wrote innerHTML instead of value as Emre Piskin said below and its working good for now. Thanks for the help i just joined stack and im pretty new to js so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't forget to define your variables first.
- Use `innerHTML` instead of `value`.
- Class name was re**s** while you were calling for re**z**.

Try this one:

```js
function calculate() {
    var teza = 5,
        visina = 3,
        bmi = teza / (visina * visina);

    document.getElementsByClassName("res")[0].innerHTML = bmi;
}
```

```html
  <div class="panel-body">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <p><b>BMI za izbrano osebo:</b></p>
    <div class="res"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your class selector I think.
Try this for show the value :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("res")[0].innerHTML = bmi;
```